# Magento 2: How to remove category layered navigation from search result

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, catalogsearch

In Magento2.4.x how to hide categories from left side layered navigation on search result page only.
Is there any setting/configuration or will have to do through code
There is a configuration here Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog
But not specific to the search result page

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can override this file

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml
```

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_CatalogSearch/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml

and add this code

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="catalogsearch.leftnav" remove="true" />
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional" remove="true" />
```

Comment: This will remove the whole left sidebar, I want to remove the categories filter only.